# Allow linking to specific revision of revision history showing diff

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, diff

Currently, the only way to link to a revision (clicking "link"), you just get [a page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/58035/8) which shows what the post looked like at that revision:

> [image]

Personally, I rarely use this and haven't ever found myself in a scenario (as far as I remember) where I would prefer the way it currently works to what I'm suggesting here.

Could we:

- Add another link, or
- Change the current link

Such that it:

- Displays the diff on a separate page (I'd prefer this, since the highlight and scroll thing doesn't always work properly - although perhaps it has something to do with loading images, so it might not apply here, or, if it doesn't, we could fix that instead), or

> [image]

- Highlights and scrolls to a diff, like what is done when you link to an answer ([possible URL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/58035/revisions#8))

> [image]

Comment: There are linkable ids in the HTML source, but not having to use browser dev tools to extract them would be helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You mean [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/58035/revisions#rev-arrow-7d876bad-b7ba-442b-96b1-84cf690b349a)? Seems like a URL that could be changed at any time.

Comment: @Dukeling this looks like a GUID (unique id) and is according to SEDE the way revisions are identified in Stack Exchange. Only problem is when the page of the revision changes.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, there is a user script to mitigate the issue: [Revision diff view](https://stackapps.com/q/10395/77981) (written by yours truly).

This only adds the diff for those who have the script installed, and it defaults to no diff view.  But it still makes a specific revision’s diff more accessible than it would be otherwise, and suggests a way to point to a specific revision’s diff by simply linking to that revision’s individual page (`/revisions/⟨post id⟩/⟨revision number⟩`); see for yourself at https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/58035/8 (which is what [one of the comments](/q/234033/620615#comment769391_234033) attempted to link to).  Those unable to install the script may click through post history to view the diff; and it is less susceptible to link rot than a link to post history (`/posts/⟨post id⟩/revisions`), where the element anchors are undocumented, and the items may bump to another page at any time.

I otherwise concur with the feature request.  I agree this is something that should be provided out of the box.