# Need more vertical space in revision page above tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, revisions-list, whitespace

It seems that there is need to add more vertical space in post revision page when the tags and the [last post line are modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions#rev-arrow-16437c75-54b1-4b5f-af9f-b7c32b2900b6):

> [image: Screenshot demonstrating the missing space issue]

Comment: How much more? Would 5px be enough?

Comment: @rene I think there should be some simmetry with the top side of revision part.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I can't edit anything under 6 characters, but for the hyperlink text you forgot that "L" there

Comment: @StackExchangeTornado fixed now :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ you fixed it in the same moment when I suggested an edit fixing this and improving other issues ;)

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... hehe :) BTW, maybe your direct link to the revision is not good enough according [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234033/allow-linking-to-specific-revision-of-revision-history-showing-diff#comment769391_234033)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ see my comment on the linked thread. I am aware of that issue but for now there’s unfortunately no other way.